# Remote RAID Control in ESXi on a Dell PowerEdge 2950 Using OpenManage

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, raid, vmware-esxi, dell-poweredge

I was wondering how one can add a drive into an existing RAID array   while ESXi is still running. I have read that you are able to use Dell   OpenManage to do this. I have installed OMSA 7.0 on the VMWare ESXi  host  (5.0 and fully updated) and I've installed OpenManage Essentials  on a  Windows Server 2008 R2 guest. The issue that I'm having is that   OpenManage is unable to see my RAID controller. I have seen videos and   photos as parts of guides on how to do this online, so I would assume   that the functionality exists and I just have it set up wrong.

Comment: You already asked this question http://serverfault.com/questions/402829/remote-raid-control-in-esxi-on-a-dell-poweredge-2950-using-openmanage but I closed that as a dupe of this one for you

Comment: Okay, thanks. I was not sure how to delete the old one but i wanted to re-post as i didn't even get 1 reply before.

Comment: @yoyomommy What kind of RAID controller is it?

Answer (score 2):

It would be helpful to know the RAID controller, but I think this may be a limitation of OME+ESXi as discussed [here](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/systems-management/f/4494/t/19446745.aspx). It's possible you can manage the storage via [OMSA Managed Node](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/555/DriverDetails/DriverFileFormats?DriverId=HPRYT&FileId=2962652778) (as opposed to OME) from the Windows box.